# Inno Setup jump to specified wizard page

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

Is there a way to jump to the specified wizard page? Backward and forward?

For example, I would add "Configure again" button in the `wpReady`, and when the button is clicked, I want to jump to `wpInfoBefore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not sanely.  It's possible to fake mouseclicks on the Back/Next buttons, and use ShouldSkipPage, which would get you the desired effect, but it's very bad practice and potentially fragile.

If the user has made a mistake in the previous pages, then they should just go back however many pages are actually required (which might not be the full complement) and fix it.  This is especially important when the contents of one page are dependent on the selections made on an earlier page, as jumping back too far would typically result in some of the user's choices being discarded.

Comment: That's too bad. One simple `JumpToPage` function would be awesome. Thank you anyway.